# Spring JPA nested Exception: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I tried almost all what I could find here in SO, and another sites tutorials about creating an One to One Relationship with Hibernate.

So, I have two models, here are the last modifications, like for example the @MapsId annotation I also removed in previous test.

Usuario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="usuarios_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="usuarios_id_seq", sequenceName="usuarios_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="roles_usuarios", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="usuarios_id", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="roles_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Rol rol;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="usuario")
    private Cliente cliente;
```

Cliente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clientes")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="clientes_id_seq")
    //@SequenceGenerator(name="clientes_id_seq", sequenceName="clientes_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    //@Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    @MapsId
    private Usuario usuario;
```

Cliente Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cliente, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

        if( clienteService.isClienteExist(cliente) ){
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        clienteService.save(cliente);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setLocation( ucBuilder.path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(cliente.getId()).toUri() );

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

Cliente Service:

```
@Override
    public Cliente save(Cliente cliente) {

        Cliente clt = new Cliente();

        clt.setUsuario(cliente.getUsuario());
        clt.setRazonSocial(cliente.getRazonSocial());
        clt.setRfc(cliente.getRfc());
        clt.setDireccion(cliente.getDireccion());
        clt.setEmail(cliente.getEmail());
        clt.setTelefono(cliente.getTelefono());
        clt.setContacto(cliente.getContacto());
        clt.setTelContacto(cliente.getTelContacto());
        clt.setEmailContacto(cliente.getEmailContacto());

        return clienteRepository.save(clt);

    }
```

If you notice I also have a many to one relationship with a Rol table which works fine, but when I pass information in the OneToOne which I pass it as a JSON it produces: **detached entity passed to persist: com.swargos.entities.Usuario**

IDK if I'm missing some annotations, or is that the database is created when running the spring application.

Comment: Can you show the code which generate this exception?

Comment: I updated with code... to how I call save...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm providing a somewhat qualified guess, since you didn't include code that shows how you call persist.

The error means that the Usuario instance you are passing to persist() already has a primary key, but it is not a managed entity of that persistence context, see here for [Entity Object lifecycle](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed)

My guess is that the Usuario instance was loaded by another EntityManager, then json-serialized to the front-end, and then posted back to the backend, and you need to set it on a Cliente (Since you have cascade in both directions it may also be the Cliente  being set on the Usuario). Every time an entity has been loaded in one Persistence Context, and you want to save it in another you must either call `em.merge()` or you must call `em.find()` to load it into it (and then set the changes).

JPA is not magic, the life-cycle of the Entities and the Persistence Context which manage them is well defined, and unless the developer understands how these mechanisms work, a lot of time will be wasted trying to work against the framework.

Also @MapsId should only be used if Cliente used an @EmbeddedId for it primary key, which does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Are you sending an existing or new Usuario as part of the Cliente that the controller receives.

Comment: Existing... I think I make it work... just changed the cascade type to: cascade = CascadeType.MERGE and also remove the @MapsId annotation you said, thanks.

Comment: If you made it work by *randomly* changing the cascade type from ALL to Merge, and you think that solved your problems, then you really need to **read the documentation!** You need to understand why you got the detached error (why I asked the questions I did), without this knowledge the problem will almost certainly reappear. I have worked with JPA since 2009 and believe me, until you understand Entity lifecycle, there are a lot of error you will not understand, and you will spend a lot of time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know I know... of course I'll read the documentation but the linke you provide guide me through how to work with Detatched entities, so I tried the MERGE option. I'm new to JPA so this is very helpful... thanx a lot.

Comment: The reason your code failed is because when Cliente is new and Usuario already exists, Usuario is basically a detached entity (it was loaded by a different persistence context). Since you have cascade Persist, saving Cliente will cause save to be propagated to Usuario but since it is detached you get an error. Changing CascadeType from ALL to MERGE works because this means persist is not cascaded, but using cascade NONE would probably be more correct. But a better solution could be to merge/load the detached entity into the current persistence context.

Comment: Do you have a blog or something?? I think I understand better of your explanation that all that I'll be reading in docs and other sites...

Comment: Ok, so for clarification... First, when I pass the Usuario entity which already exists, well actually don't what I'm passing is only the id (here is where I think not doing things correctly) I thougt that jpa knows when a entity is sent (in this case as a json object), so do you mean that with this id I have to findById first, then attach it to Cliente entity?? wouldn't be as simple if Usuario were only a FK in cliente table?? Which actually is, but I don't have to make an explicit query...

Comment: I don't have a blog, but I teach a 2 day JPA course for only $1400 :-) I'm sort of between jobs, so I have decided to use a little time answering questions on SO. Your problem is quite common, and I would argue that it is because you use your Entities as front-end DTOs. I my mind there are different requirements for DTOs used for JSON serialization and database Entities, and when you use your Entities for both, you need to know a lot more about JPA than if you have separate classes for the two purposes.